# Unable to print some parts of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a english_words dataset that I load to a pandas dataframe. The data contained in the dataframe is just one column of english_words with approximately 58109 rows. When I try to do any data manipulation to the words I get the following error:

```
for i in range(0,len(english_words):
    print(i,english_words[0][i])
```

I am expecting to see all the words on my dataframe printed out.

---

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-34-8cd49c2717a5> in <module>
   1 for i in range(0,8000):
   ----> 2     print(i,english_words[0][i])

   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
    -->     868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, 
   series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
   -> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 7870
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question and provide more details? Such as, what were you expecting and do you want to achieve with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the row with index value `7870` is not in the dataframe for whatever reason. This is likely the result you transforming the dataframe, and thus the index, without realizing it.

In general, you should iterate over the index itself:

```py
for i in english_words.index.tolist():
    print(i,english_words[0][i])
```

If you want the index to be contiguous, then you should reset it after transforming the dataframe:

```py
english_words = english_words.reset_index(drop=True)
```